# Play Sound on Tab Click

Tags: android, android-widget

On an Android phone from AT&T, you can hear a click sound when navigating through tabs. How do I get the Tab widget to play a sound on the click of a tab?

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        //PLAY SOUND HERE
        MediaPlayer tabClick = MediaPlayer.create(TabBarActivity.this, R.Raw.gling_click);
        tabClick.start();
    }
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

step 1 from the tutorial is this:

```
for(int i=0;i<tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++)  
{  
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_blue_matte);  
}  
    tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(1);  
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_green_matte);  

    //NEW CODE HERE **
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            //PLAY SOUND HERE
        }

    )};
```

See where it says NEW CODE HERE **?  You want to add an OnTabChangedListener to the tabHost.  This is an object that is "listening" for the user to change tabs.  When a tab changes, the `onTabChanged(String tabID)` method is run.

Add the `onTabChangedListener` after tutorial step 1; It's within the `onCreate()` method.

Then, get on google and look up `android play a sound` and get *that* code into where it says //PLAY SOUND HERE.