# Disabling system sound effects on TabHost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost, audio

I'm trying to disable system sound effects when a user clicks on a tab in my TabHost and to set my own custom sound. So I tried this to disable the system sound effect:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
tabHost.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
```

And this is my code to play my custom sound:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        SoundUtility.getInstance(MainActivity.this).playPositive();
    }
});
```

My custom sound does play, but also the system sound effect, it's not being disabled. So I actually have 2 sounds overlapping each other.
So how do I disable the system sound effect?

Comment: have you try it on tabChangeListener ??

Comment: @iDroidExplorer Yup, tried it. Tried to use `tabHost.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);` on tabChangeListener, also tried to disable it on the currently pressed tab (but didn't write the code right, the app crashed).

Comment: can you put that code ? and also show at which line you got crashed.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I already deleted this code... I just tried this code: `TabWidget tw = (TabWidget) tabHost.getTabWidget();
             tw.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);` both in onCreate and in onTabChangeListener, but still no luck.

Comment: have you refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237097/play-sound-on-tab-click

Comment: Well, they show how to play a custom sound and I already do that. My problem is how to disable the system sound effect, to hear only my sound, not android's native sound as well...

Comment: I got the same problem, and i found this [a good solution][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5504676/1048872